# maven build dependencies in Eclipse, multiple projects

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

I have two projects in eclipse, both are maven controlled.  A references B and they are on a flat system.  What we currently have setup is that we have to a build on B - generate a jar on the system, and A references that jar.

I'd like to change this to be we just have to build A and it will go automatically build B?  Can I do this in Maven/eclipse such that I don't have to create some higher project?

I have looked into some of the maven docs - but they just really confuse me :).  Thanks for your help.

The pom's look like this

(B)

```
    <project xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..."
 xsi:schemaLocation="...">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.thetus</groupId>
 <artifactId>irisMDK</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <name>irisMDK</name>
 <version>0.1</version>
 <url>...maven.apache...</url>
 <build>
  <sourceDirectory>java/src/main</sourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <source>1.6</source>
     <target>1.6</target>
     <testExcludes>
      <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
     </testExcludes>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
  <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>java/src/main</directory>
   </resource>
  </resources>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
  ...
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

------ And (A):

```
 <project xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..."
 xsi:schemaLocation="...">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>local.b</groupId>
 <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <name>B</name>
 <version>RELEASE</version>
 <url>...</url>
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
   <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
   <url>...download.java.net/maven...</url>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
 <build>
  <plugins>
                   ...
  </plugins>
  <sourceDirectory>java/src/main</sourceDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>java/src/test</testSourceDirectory>
  <resources>
  </resources>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>local.b</groupId>
   <artifactId>projectB</artifactId>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <version>RELEASE</version>
   <systemPath>${basedir}/../B/target/B-0.1.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>
 ...
 </dependencies>
 <reporting>
  ...
 </reporting>
</project>
```

If you could show me an example of how to change ^^^ I would be most grateful!!

Answer (score 4):

Original Answer:
The [M2Eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin, if you are not using it already, allows you to do this.  Once installed, remove

```
<systemPath>${basedir}/../B/target/B-0.1.jar</systemPath>
```

from A's pom.xml and make sure the groupid, artifactid, version match up with what is defined in B's pom.xml

Then right-click on the project, Maven-> Enable Dependency Resolution.  The build should now look at B's local project

Edit:

If B's pom.xml looks like this (from your example):

```
<project xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..."
      xsi:schemaLocation="...">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>com.thetus</groupId>
      <artifactId>irisMDK</artifactId>
      <packaging>jar</packaging>
      <name>irisMDK</name>
      <version>0.1</version>

      ...
 </project>
```

In A's pom (which depends on Project B) your dependency should look like:

```
<project>
...
    <dependencies>
      <!--Attributes of project that this project is dependent upon, as defined in that projects POM -->
      <dependency>
           <groupId>com.thetus</groupId>
           <artifactId>irisMDK</artifactId>
           <version>0.1</version>
      </dependency>
 ...
     </dependencies>
....
</project>
```

This will tell maven and eclipse that project A explicitly depends on that version of Project B. With M2Eclipse, if you have a matching groupId, artifactId, and version in your workspace and you have "Dependency Resolution" enabled, Project B's contents will automatically be built and included into Project A.

Also, opening the Maven console in eclipse (console view->new console dropdown->new maven console) could help in debugging why project B isn't be picked up by Project A.

Comment: I am using that plugin, and have that in there, but unless I have build that jar it won't find it.  I'd like it to build the Jar for me :)

Comment: You may need to change the scope to "compile" (i.e. not "system") for the workspace resolution to work. After making the changes outlined by @BuffaloBuffalo, you might also need to right click on the project and select "Maven->Update Project Configuration".

Comment: @jt Thats what I was just looking at--It also looks like in your example for A's pom, your dependency for B has a separate version than what you have defined in B's pom.xml's version

Comment: I get the error regarding that.  I thought you could only have "systemPath" specified if the scope is "system".

Comment: Could I potentially put up a local repo?  at 'file://$(basedir)/..' and then change the groupid to 'ProjectB' (the project is named ProjectB)?

Comment: Edited my answer to provide clarification for how A's dependency on Project B should be declared in A's pom.xml

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to use a multi-module project, [here](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule-sect-intro.html) is a simple tutorial.  You would create a parent POM, and have both A and B as children, with A keeping its dependency on B.

Comment: That is what I'd like to do, but I don't have access to the higher levels of the tree (some one else controls the SVN and we can't get access higher)

Comment: Well either the two projects are conceptually linked, in which case you should move them into a common parent folder at their current level in the tree, or they are infact separate projects, in which case building them together doesn't make sense.

Comment: The old link was to codehaus which as been killed off, I've updated it with a link to the maven by example book

Comment: @rybit you can alternatively create a modules project on the same level and instead of `<module>moduleA</module>` you specify `<module>../moduleA</module>`